# How to allow user to enter email in QueryString in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

User will type `www.abc.com/Email/abc@abc.com`

above code not work, It generates the error,

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:

The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.

The URL contains a typographical error.

A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:

Create the content on the Web server.

Review the browser URL.

Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.

Comment: put a slash in between and try for ex :-www.abc.com/Email/abc/@abc.com

Comment: it generates the same error. :(

Comment: or if you want email in querystring then www.abc.com/Email/abc?email=@abc.com

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake, i dont want to send as a queryString, but  as a Route value

Comment: just post your code in routconfig file

Comment: Sorry but how as i am new to MVC

Comment: there is a folder in your project as app_start and in it there is routeconfig file just post it's code here

Answer (score 0):

Please read more here http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/.

You should encode @ to '%40' and decode it back to @ in your MVC action.

To decode you can use `encodeURIComponent` 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent

you can use `UrlDecode` on backed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx